# why Object.keys(Array.prototype) returns empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Following this code first:

```
function User(name, dept){
    this.username = name;
    this.dept = dept;
    this.talk = function(){
        return "Hi";
    };
}

function Employee(){
    User.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
}

Employee.prototype = new User();


for(var x in Employee.prototype) 
    console.log(x, ':', Employee.prototype[x]);

Object.keys(Employee.prototype);//prints array of keys...
```

It prints out fine...

```
Array.prototype; //[]
Array.prototype.slice; // Function

var o = Array.prototype;

for(var i in o) console.log(i, ':', o[i]); //it doesn't execute
Object.keys(Array.prototype); //[] - ???
```

How to explain this behaviour?

Can we mimic this for constructors we try to create?

Comment: Because they are non-enumerable properties.

Comment: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype)

Comment: About time someone answered this... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Object.keys() - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**

> The [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method returns an array of a given object's own **enumerable** properties...

We can check whether a given property is enumerable:

```
Array.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable('push');
// false
```

Alternatively we can get a full descriptor for the object's property, which will also include the enumerability flag.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype, 'push');
// {writeable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
```

The properties on [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) are deliberately **non-enumerable** so that they don't show up in [`for...in` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).